# Are Wordpress plugin code open to public view

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am new to wordpress plugin codes.

I am following some tutorials and I see that I am able to get into the plugin code using cPanel, FileZila etc.

So, if I get into wordpress plugin development, how do I ensure that my code is not available to people else what is the point in making paid version of plugin codes if the code becomes open right after install. Of course I can offer subscription for maintenance etc. but in general the code will be open to public once it gets installed on 3rd party server?

Comment: yes they are, you can download the plugin in your pc, you can load the plugin to your website through FTP, you can navigate through the code and modify the code as much as you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to clarify: **You will never be able to create a plugin that cannot be cracked in one way or the other**. This is, unfortunately, part of WordPress being open-source and thus accessible and extendable by basically anyone who wishes to.

However, there are methods to make it harder for users to get hold of the premium version for free. Most developers create a free version that is hosted on WordPress.org's public repository and contains a link, banner, or any other information that lets users upgrade to the pro version.

The pro version, then, is usually either an extension to the free plugin, which means the user must activate both the free and the pro plugin, or a license somehow protects the pro version. Licensing plugins is relatively unsafe, though. You only need one user who's willing to share a licensed version of a plugin, and it's easy to remove the license check within the plugin files.

**Not to mention that most nulled plugins and themes contain malware and can be a huge security risk for your site.**

Most, if not all, of the popular plugins you see on the internet already exist as a cracked (the correct term here is *nulled*, [which you should avoid](https://wpulike.com/blog/wp-ulike-pro-nulled/)) version. Long story short: You will never be able to 100% avoid users from "stealing" or "nulling" the pro version of your plugin.

You can try encrypting certain parts that are crucial to the licensing mechanism, e.g., using Base64 to MD5 hashes to encrypt serial numbers or hide the relevant check mechanisms in an obscure part of your code. However, it'll only be a better of time until someone will [figure out how to null it](https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/how-to-null-a-wordpress-plugin.957012/).

I'm sorry for the bad news, but this is how it is.

[Here is some more information](https://markosaric.com/secure-wordpress/) on how to beef-up your WordPress security when it comes to development. Also, please refer to the official handbook; it has [a lot of useful information](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/).

Comment: The open source nature of the software has absolutely nothing to do with this. Open source just means you have the legal right to distribute the code; I can give `<?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>` a proprietary license but it's still easily "cracked". "it's one of the downsides of open-source software" is quite simply false; it's one of the downsides of *any* code or other IP you distribute to other people. (See, for example, movie piracy.)

Comment: Thanks for downvoting my answer, this is really encouraging after trying my best to help others in the community. Never mind, what I meant was the fact that the open-source approach came as a way to encourage collaboration for decentralized peer-production which was a response to the (heavy) limitation of proprietary code. My argument was: The more public a code is, the more available it is for people who have ulterior motives, thus increasing the likelihood that it may contain harmful elements. If I'm wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: I will happily remove the downvote if the falsehoods about open source are removed. The problem is the distribution of the plugin's code to potentially untrusted actors, not the open source license of the underlying blogging platform.

Comment: I've absolutely no problem when I'm wrong; to me, that's what websites like this are about: learning from others. I'm going to remove that line since you seem to have a more accurate understanding of this particular information. If you remove the downvote or not, it is up to you; I'd just like to mention that it's a bit discouraging for new users like me to be "punished" for making small mistakes in a post that was meant to help a stranger. Cheers!

Comment: @thaikolja You might be a "new user" but your answer is eye opening. I was making all these big plans but I didn't know that it was that easy to null the wordpress plugin. No doubt some ideas that I have, have never been implemented as it is just too easy to null them.

Comment: Another part of this discussion which is a good news is that since the code is "open", it is unlikely a developer with long term plans will put malicious code in it. i.e. it gives confidence of using open source codes, 1000 eyes are looking at it.

Comment: @Zanam You're right, but there are also cases of people buying popular plugins and then using them to insert malicious code, quietly. Sure, this doesn't happen on a daily basis, but some big cases have been reported in the past.